# Minecraft, How to testfor player on specific coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know `/testfor @a[x=400,y=4,z=Z,r=600]`, but that is not working if I write it like this... I tried to remove , or `[]`, but still nothing. How can I make it work? (1.11.2)

Answer (score 2):

The capital `Z` needs to be replaced with a number.

You also probably want to reduce the radius from 600.

For example:

```
/testfor @a[x=400,y=4,z=10,r=2]
```